# Repeating nested functions in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to use one single formula across multiple cells for calculating a value, dependent on the specific row and column of which the formula is applied, but relative to the row itself. Sounds a little cryptic, so an example:

I have the following three rows,
Row 91: 10|Wheat|60,00|0,00
Row 92: 11|Banana|91,20|1,00
Row 93: 12|Milk|200,00|182,00

Where the | represents a separation between each column, which are named by letter (as Excel does by default). So the value of cell A92 would be 11. Now, column D is generated using the following formula: `=((C92/100)*D11)`, basically taking the value of cell C92 (91,20) dividing it by 100, and then multiplying it by whatever value is held in cell D11 (the same column as the one I am generating a value in, but using the value from column A for reference of what value to multiply by).

Now, seeing as I need to use this formula in many rows, I want to basically to something like this: `=VALUE(=CONCATENATE("D"; ROW();)/100)*CELL("address"))`, but this is not a valid formula. To put it in words:

1. Get the value of cell D+current row number (for example D9 at row 9 etc.)
2. Divide this by 100
3. Multiply this by the value of current column letter+current row number (E69 at cell E69 etc.)

I hope someone has an idea of how to achieve this.

Comment: You can't meet condition 3 with a formula because it requires a circular reference.

Comment: You can use **INDIRECT()** to deal with #3.  You could also use it for #1 but that seems like it would be unnecessary: just drag down the formula and Excel will automatically adjust the reference.  You should be aware though that using INDIRECT might cause problems with recalculation: your indirect-ly referenced cells will not be flagged as precedents by excel, so if they change, your formula might not be recalculated.

Comment: whats wrong with `=($C92/100)*$D$11` instead of `=((C92/100)*D11)`.  The `$`'s anchor those parts of the references o they dont change when you copy the formula.

Comment: @Time using `INDIRECT` makes the formula Volitile, meaning it calculates every time the sheet recalculates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with OFFSET, but you may very well get circular references or errors if your data is not clean.

`=(C92/100)*OFFSET(D92,$A92-ROW(),0,1,1)`

The OFFSET says: Get the value of a 1 row 1 column range that is (the value in A92 - current row number) rows offset from this row, but in the current column), which for your data is D11

Comment: I tweaked your solution a little, to come up with: =($C92/100)*OFFSET(D92;OFFSET($A92;0;0;)-ROW();0;1;1) which generates 200,64 in cell D92 (for a value of 220 in cell D11, this yields (91,2/100)*220 which equals 200,64). Also accepted your answer as closest to the solution I was looking for.

Comment: Don't think you need your OFFSET($A92;0;0) its the same as just $A92

Answer (score 0):

I think this should do your job:

```
Sub Test()
    Cells(ActiveCell.Row, "D").FormulaR1C1 = "=RC" & ActiveCell.Column & "*RC3/100"
End Sub
```

Comment: @Neil: it's a macro you can save in your excel file and call whenever you please. If you assign it a shortcut this operation will be faster.

Comment: Is this only possible using a macro? I am somewhat dependent on maintaining compatibility and would greatly prefer compiling it into a formula that I could replicate in other code languages. Also, memory usage/performance isn't an issue as there aren't that many rows in total.